# Is it same number of candies for any stage of evolution while transferring pokemon to professor?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was just wondering if the number of candies we get while transferring the pokemon to professor is same for any stage of evolution ?

For example, you would get a pidgey candy for transferring a pidgey. Is it same number of candies for transferring pidgey, pidgeotto or pidgeot ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**YES.**

The number is 1 candy per transfer to the Professor regardless of the position in the evolution chain.

Source: Personal experience. Tested it with exactly your example (pidgey, pidgeotto or pidgeot) and others. And I also tested it with high CP evolutions (e.g. Raticate for which I need 2 candies for Power-Up also gives only 1 candy at transfer.) What isn't secure: A Gyarados - to give an example - might bring more than one as it needs 400 (!) candies to evolve and seems to follow no rule in this regard.

Comment: Gyrados does what he pleases. Also I can confirm this. I have traded in a bunch of low cp evolved Pokémon to evolve better ones.